# Hilbert And Banach dual spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, dual-spaces

Are, and in general, all **Hilbert** spaces identified to their *dual* ?, i.e $H'\equiv H$

What about **Banach spaces**? And can someone please state the *weak convergence* in each?

Answer (score -1):

A vector space (*a fortiori*, Hilbert space, Banach space) is isomorphic to its dual if, and only if, it is finite dimensional. For any infinite dimensional vector space, the dual space is always "larger" than the predual, in the precise technical sense that there exists an injection from the predual into the dual, but never a bijection.

Additionally, the isomorphism between a finite dimensional vector space and its dual is dependent on a choice of vector basis. It is not a "natural" isomorphism, in the language of category theory. However, the isomorphism between a vector space and its double dual (the dual of the dual) IS natural, in that it can be defined without a choice of basis.

Studying this phenomenon is anecdotally what pushed Saunders MacLane and Samuel Eilenberg to invent category theory, by the way.

Edit: I was mistaken in the above, due to an ambiguity on the notion of "dimension" as used by an algebraist, and as used by an analyst; and have provided in the comments below a document which clarifies my point, and explains my mistake in your specific context.

Comment: Usually in this context the "dual" is the space of _continuous_  linear functionals. With that definition any Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to its dual, regardless of dimension.

Comment: Indeed, I did not know that. Thanks. For the asker, here's a small document which explains our disagreement: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/dualspaceinfinite.pdf